PHPIPam Curl Bringing Conflicting Response
Curl seems to be giving me conflicting response when i POST, GET or PATCH.
Using POST/GET i can see that my target IP address (10.130.9.35) exists as below. However, trying to update it using PATCH results in an error.
GET:
-Message:curl -X GET https://xxxxxxxx/phpipam/api/dev/addresses/ --header 'token: xxxxxxxxxx' --header "Content-Type: application/json"

-Response: {"id":"15","subnetId":"13","ip":"**10.130.9.35**","is_gateway":"0","description":"12345","hostname":null,"mac":null,"owner":null,"tag":"2","deviceId":null,"location":null,"port":null,"note":null,"lastSeen":"1970-01-01 00:00:01","excludePing":"0","PTRignore":"0","PTR":"0","firewallAddressObject":null,"editDate":null,"customer_id":null,"custom_Location (Coordinates)":null,"custom_Latitude":"12345","custom_Longitude":"12345","custom_CID":"12345"}


POST:
-Message: curl -s -X POST --data '{"subnetId":"'13'","ip":"'**10.130.9.35**'","description":"'12345'","custom_CID":"'12345'","custom_Latitude":"'12345'","custom_Longitude":"'12345'" }' https://xxxxxxxxxx/phpipam/api/dev/addresses --header 'token: xxxxxxxxx' --header "Content-Type: application/json"

-Response: {"code":409,"success":false,"message":"**IP address already exists**","time":0.006}

However, trying to update the address using PATCH gives me an "Address does not exist"
PATCH:
-Message:curl -X PATCH --data '{"custom_CID":"'12345'","description":"'12345'","custom_Latitude":"'12345'","custom_Longitude":"'12345'"}' https://xxxxxxx/phpipam/api/dev/addresses/**10.130.9.35**/ --header 'token: xxxxxxxxx' --header "Content-Type: application/json"

-Response: {"code":404,"success":false,"message":"**Address does not exist**","time":0.004}

What could be the Issue?
